# How to change the `blank gray squares` in OSMdroid maps when the map cannot be loaded?

Tags: java, android, maps, osmdroid

I want to change the "raw" squares to a png file stating "you should either download offline maps or go online" when the maps cannot be loaded in osmdroid.
How can I achieve this? I couldn't find a file in the library that has this asset

Answer (score 0):

Mapview.getOverlayManager ().getTilesOverlay ().setLoadingBackground (....)

Comment: Unfortunately there are only two methods on `getTilesOverlay()` that can set the background and they are `setLoadingBackgroundColor` and `setLoadingLineColor`